# How can I use the default generic kernel in a UEC Ubuntu Cloud Image?

Tags: kernel, cloud, openstack, disk-image, uec

I download a UEC style Ubuntu Precise image from http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ that I want to use in an OpenStack cloud, but I want to make some modifications to it before booting the VM.

Installing packages is fairly straight forward. I first mount `precise-server-cloudimg-amd64.img` and use `apt-get` after chroot-ing to the mounted folder. However, I also want to remove the default `linux-image-virtual` kernel (and `precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual`) and install and use the `linux-image-generic` one.

How can I achieve this in a chroot environment that I have mounted the cloud image?